# Background images not showing in IE11

Tags: css, background-image, internet-explorer-11

For some reason, background images are not showing up at all in IE11 (Windows 7 Pro).

```
.home {
position:relative;
height: 620px;
background-image: url(/images/bg_home3.jpg);
background-position: 540px 190px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: did you try to specify a width for the class?

Comment: specify the width and quote the url for the image

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to set background to HTML5 element there is a chance that it doesn't have some default style in IE11. For example if the element is main try to set display: block to it. You may also try to set width, but without seeing more of your code can't help you more. Look the example below.

```
.home {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    height: 620px;
    background-image: url("/images/bg_home3.jpg");
    background-position: 540px 190px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Had the same problem and for me, it was the `display: block` that the IE was missing

Answer (score 1):

necessary use `width: 100px;` <= you size px

```
.home {
position:relative;
height: 620px;
width: 200px;
background-image: url('/images/bg_home3.jpg');
background-position: 540px 190px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think with two easy steps you can eliminate the problem:

1. Set **display: block;** The display property specifies the display behavior on your page. IE 8 and upper versions fully supports this property.
2. Put your url between quotation marks ("").
   **background-image: url("/images/something.jpg");**

Answer (score 0):

Use a png image as it seems IE 11 cannot display jpg with non web colors.

Answer (score 0):

I found setting the background size of the image made it display in **IE11**.

I also had to set the `width` and `height`. Setting the value of these attributes to `auto` it didn't work.