# Website background image not displaying on internet explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have set background image, it is working fine on other browsers like chrome and mozilla but it's not displaying on internet explorer 11. What could be the reason?

```css
.body-w0s67w {
  height: 84vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black, black), url(https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/ratchet-and-clank_bGpmZ2qUmZqaraWkpJRmbmdlrWZlbWU.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-blend-mode: saturation;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body class="body-w0s67w"></body>
```

Comment: Why do you have a class on the body, just use `body` or is it s a different element? If so, show us - update the snippet I made you with relevant HTML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background images not showing in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903291/background-images-not-showing-in-ie11)

Comment: @mplungjan, i use it on that class just that it don't cover the whole background just certain area i defined